# PostgreSQL: Browsing built-in schemas in pgAdmin UI

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

PostgreSQL comes with below built-in schemas

```
postgres=# select catalog_name, schema_name, schema_owner
postgres-# from information_schema.schemata
postgres-# order by schema_name;
 catalog_name |    schema_name     | schema_owner
--------------+--------------------+--------------
 postgres     | information_schema | postgres
 postgres     | pg_catalog         | postgres
 postgres     | pg_toast           | postgres
 postgres     | public             | postgres
(4 rows)
```

EDB Postgres Advanced Server has 4 additional ones

```
postgres=# select catalog_name, schema_name, schema_owner
postgres-# from information_schema.schemata
postgres-# order by schema_name;
 catalog_name |    schema_name     | schema_owner
--------------+--------------------+--------------
 postgres     | information_schema | enterprisedb
 postgres     | pg_catalog         | enterprisedb
 postgres     | pg_temp_1          | enterprisedb
 postgres     | pg_toast           | enterprisedb
 postgres     | pg_toast_temp_1    | enterprisedb
 postgres     | public             | enterprisedb
 postgres     | sys                | enterprisedb
(7 rows)
```

In particular I'm interested in `information_schema` and `sys` schemas but they are not visible in object browser.

I presume that might be an issue with permission or with connection settings or with something else...

Is there any way to make those schemas visible in object browser along with corresponding objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are under the `catalogs` section

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it does not display functions, types, packages, etc for information_schema/sys. If you have Advanced Server those objects can be returned with something like `select * from dba_objects where schema_name in ('SYS', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA') and object_type in ('PACKAGE', 'TYPE')`